# Customizing a feature: Site Options? Config List? Something else?

Tags: 2010, development, feature, configuration

I'm developing a feature that renders a link on the user's screen, and I need that link's destination URL to be configurable by site collection administrators (SCAs) who are not developers.

Where should I put that URL such that the SCAs can edit it any time *and* my code can read it?

I see Site Options (in SPD) and a configuration list as two options. I don't know which of those would be better/worse, and I'm curious to know what other choices I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this link is displayed in multiple locations, then a configuration list item on site collection root is perhaps the best place. Or even links list, and then use CQWP to display the item from that list.

If this is a link just on one page, maybe a Content Editor Web Part might work.

Answer (score 1):

Links list.

You can make it hidden, so most users won't see it. Use a CustomAction to put a link to the list on the Site Actions menu, or on the Site Settings page. The custom action can be coded to only display for adminitrators.